# .htaccess Block PHP Referer File access

Tags: .htaccess

I have a PHP file on my server and I don't want anyone without the correct refer to access it.

This is my current rule that is working.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .streamer\.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*domain.com.*
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Is this rule is friendly enough for `mod_rewrite`? Or does it need cleaning or tidying up a bit? It does function but I am no expert with `mod_rewrite` and I am sure there may be a better code than my method.

Comment: Referrers can be spoofed. Why do you need to do that? There’s probably an easier (and more secure) way, like sessions.

Comment: I know they can be spoofed i am not worried about that i could input sessions into the php file but right now i am more interested in tidying up my existing functioning code.

Comment: So tidy that up and use sessions. (It’s not even necessary that everyone has referrers turned on.)

Comment: But I'm trying to block hot linking and even when i add guest sessions i get the feeling that alone will not help since allot of users who do need to stream data are legit guests i do not want to block them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the `%{REQUEST_URI}` condition with the rule itself, and you can clean up the referer regex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://[^/]+\.domain\.com/? [NC]
RewriteRule .streamer\.php - [F]
```

Note that this will also block blank referers, like if you copy and paste a link straight into the browser's URL address bar. If you want to allow blank referers, you'll need to add an extra condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://[^/]+\.domain\.com/? [NC]
RewriteRule .streamer\.php - [F]
```