# protect files in website by making it forbidden

Tags: javascript, php, html, security

Hi let's say that I have a page www.example.com/main.html and inside of that I have

```
<source src="myfile" >
```

How can I make this file readable only if the user accesses it from www.example.com/main.html

So if a user tries to go to www.example.com/myfile it will return a forbidden error, and keep the file `myfile` safe.

I think this may involve changing file permissions but I don't know how to do that when the page main.html is the user.

THANKS!

Comment: got any user management going on?

Comment: (i.e access by login)

Comment: @Dagon not sure if I'm understanding you but yes I have a user

Comment: so wrap it in a user check. `if($user == 'bob'){ ..`

Comment: If you don't want to use login credentials, you can allow only your site to refer to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259942/htaccess-block-php-referer-file-access

Comment: I don't wat that i.e only bob to see it. I want all to see it but only if they are in main.html file

Comment: How is the file being accessed? For example PHP's `include` or HTML's `iframe` or any other techniques?